# Is it possible to run C# on Up and Down migrations in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We have a number of tables that contain JSON data. This data will need to be migrated from time to time. These JSON manipulations will likely be to complex to do directly in SQL. We would like to run C# to migrate this data. As far as I know there is no way to do this in the framework natively.

We tried using the DbMigrator class to get the applied migrations and the Seed method in the DbMigrationsConfiguration to then run the C# migrations based on the diff. Although this works for Up, unfortunately Seed isn't called on Down. See code below.

```
public abstract class CodeDbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
  readonly string[] _InitialDbMigrations;
  protected IDictionary<string, DbCodeMigration<TContext>> CodeMigrations { get; private set; }

  public CodeDbMigrationsConfiguration()
  {
    _InitialDbMigrations = new DbMigrator(this)
      .GetDatabaseMigrations()
      .ToArray();
    CodeMigrations = new Dictionary<string, DbCodeMigration<TContext>>();
  }

  protected override void Seed(TContext context)
  {
    if (CodeMigrations.Count > 0)
    {
      var currentMigrations = new DbMigrator(this)
        .GetDatabaseMigrations()
        .ToArray();

      var update = GetMigrationUpdate(_InitialDbMigrations, currentMigrations);

      DbCodeMigration<TContext> migration;
      foreach (var name in update.Down)
        if (CodeMigrations.TryGetValue(name, out migration))
          migration.Down(context);

      foreach (var name in update.Up)
        if (CodeMigrations.TryGetValue(name, out migration))
          migration.Up(context);
    }

    base.Seed(context);
  }
  //...
}
```

I thought about inheriting from DbMigrator and just wrapping the Update method but I can't find a way of forcing the tools (Visual Studio and Migrate.exe) to use my DbMigrator. Anyone have any ideas on how to run C# code on migrating up and down?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do here.  You want your `Seed` method to iterate through and run all the migrations? this doesn't make sense.  Migrations trigger the Seed, not the other way around....

Comment: If you notice the class DbCodeMigration<TContext> is my class not to be confused with the DbMigration class in EF.

I want EF to run all the standard DbMigrations then I want to run my custom C# migrations (DbCodeMigration). I was just using the Seed method as my trigger to initiate the custom code migrations.